# TFS 2010 Invoke built-in activity from custom CodeActivity

Tags: .net

I'm trying to invoke a built-in activity from my custom CodeActivity for the TFS2010 Build Process.

I've got my own CodeActivity which generates a batch file and I want to invoke the InvokeProcess activity (built-in) to execute that generated file.

Of course I could split it into two activities, but it would be nicer if I could put these actions together. Can somebody push me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OMG, they are using WWF in TFS now??  Part of me just died...

Comment: Yes the TFS Build process has been rewritten and now uses WWF. If you ask me its way better now, easier to maintain and easier to customize... well except for this situation ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by splitting it into two activities. 
Generation of the file (now XML file) is done by a custom activity.

If this activity completes, the InvokeProcess activity is called.